# Parsing prospero parameters

Tags: java, parsing, unit-testing, url

[Prospero is a URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4157). There you have fields and values.

Could you check this code and give common suggestions or even test cases for JUnit tests?

(The documentation is in German.)

```
/**
 * Gibt einen Prospero-Parameter aus der URL zurück. Dabei wird nur der Prospero-Part geprüft.
 * 
 * @param url Die URL, darf nicht <code>null</code> sein.
 * @param name Der Name des Parameters, darf kein '=' enthalten, darf nicht <code>null</code>
 *            sein.
 * @return Den Wert des Parameters oder
 *         <dl>
 *         <dt><code>null</code></dt>
 *         <dd>wenn der Parameter ohne <code>=</code> angegeben wurde.</dd>
 *         <dt><code>error</code>-Parameter</dt>
 *         <dd>wenn kein solcher Parameter gefunden wurde</dd>
 *         </dl>
 */
public static String getProsperoParam(URL url, String name, String error) {
    String path = url.getPath();
    String[] split = path.split(";", 2);
    if (split.length == 2) {
        String params = split[1];
        for (String param : params.split("&")) {
            String[] paramParts = param.split("=", -1);
            if (paramParts.length == 1) {
                if (name.equals(paramParts[0])) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            if (paramParts.length == 2) {
                if (name.equals(paramParts[0]))
                    return paramParts[1];
            }
            if (paramParts.length > 2) {
                if (name.equals(paramParts[0])) {
                    return param.substring(name.length() + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

I successfully tested these cases:

```
assert URLTools.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a?a=a#a"), "a", null) == null;
assert URLTools.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a;a=4?a=a#a"), "a", null).equals("4");
assert URLTools.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a;a=4=a?a=a#a"), "a", null).equals("4=a");
assert URLTools.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a;a=4=a&m=3?a=a#a"), "m", null).equals("3");
String missingString = "Missing!";
assert URLTools.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a;a=4=a&m=3?a=a#a"), "e", missingString) == missingString;
assert URLTools.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a;e?a=a#a"), "e", "asdf") == null;
assert URLTools.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a;e=?a=a#a"), "e", null).equals("");
```

Comment: you might want to mention what a `Prospero` is (and what `Prospero-Parameter` and `Prospero-Part` specifically are). I tried google, but the third result is already this question. It seems to be just a normal URL parameter?

Comment: Do you actually need to distinguish the edge cases (parameter without value, empty value, value with `=` included) and can't just throw them out as invalid?

Comment: @ferada yes i need them. A empty value != missing value != missing key != not set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Check input**

Your comments mention that `url` shouldn't be null, so it's best to make sure that it really isn't:

```
    if (url == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("url cannot be null");
    }
```

**Nested if statements**

> ```
>         if (paramParts.length == 1) {
>             if (name.equals(paramParts[0])) {
>                 return null;
>             }
>         }
> ```

You have this principle three times. It can be written as:

```
        if (paramParts.length == 1 && name.equals(paramParts[0])) {
            return null;
        }
```

Although I would rewritten your `if` statements like this:

```
        if (paramParts.length > 0 &&  name.equals(paramParts[0])) {
            switch(paramParts.length) {
                case 1:
                    return null;
                case 2:
                    return paramParts[1];
                default:
                    return param.substring(name.length() + 1);
            }
        }
```

And are you sure that `paramParts.length == 2` (now `case 2`) is really needed? I think the other cases cover it.

**Use early return**

If you return early, you can reduce nesting:

```
if (split.length != 2) {
    return error;
}
```

**Tests**

The specification for prosperos says:

> each field/value pair is separated from each other and from the rest of the URL by a ";" (semicolon).

You are never testing if this would work, and it wouldn't:

```
String prosperoParam = prospero.getProsperoParam(new URL("http://a:a@a.a.a/a.a;a=a;b=b"), "b", null);
assertEquals(prosperoParam, "b");
```

If you want to change the spec, I would comment on it in the Java doc (something like: `See RFC 4157, but note that this implementation uses '&' instead of ';' for the separation of field/value pairs (it still does use ';' for the separation between the first field/value pair and the rest of the URL)`.

Also, sometimes you use `==` to compare strings in your tests, I would replace it with `equals`.

Comment: I realy need == on Strings(!), its not allowed to replace it with `equals` because i would not be able to check if the value is a real parameter-value or my error-value.

Comment: I unlike to throw a IAE, a NPE will be thrown anyway and the need to catch a IAE+NPE instead of NPE only unneccessary complex.

Comment: I have edited my question. You are right, `&` is not a valid seperator for RFC4157.

Comment: @PeterRader, for IAE vs NPE, one school of thought is to consult what the Javadocs have to say for both exceptions. IAE is "thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument", while NPE is "thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required". It certainly seems that if `null` is an *inappropriate method argument* for your method, throwing IAE would be clearer. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter

Comment: This is not an so important discussion, i can do it or i can let it be. If you guys gets upset, i'll accept it. Hey, if i like to become a ranter i should use Both: `IAE(NPE)`. Even the implementation of `.split(` dont care about the more specific-qualified `IAE(NPE)` but i have to, am i something better?! Well i feel dirty if i throw a more-specific-qualified-exception without write it into the JavaDoc. But if i write it into the JavaDoc, it must match the Method's signature. And then Checkstyle will critizise me to have unchecked exceptions in the Method's signature. Life isnt Ponyhof. ;)

Comment: I tend to throw a `IAE` only in the case if `name` contains an `=`.

Comment: @h.j.k. Sorry the Stackoverflow-Question belongs to a setter, a setter will not produce a `NPE`.

Comment: @PeterRader you are right, even oracle handles this quite inconsistently. `Matcher:usePattern` does check, and throws an `IAE`, `Scanner:hasNext` does check, but throws a  `NPE`. I didn't find any cases for public methods that don't check at all, but they may exist (I would prefer checking, some methods might produce side-effects otherwise). It seems that `NPE` is actually more common; there even exists a method for it: `Objects:requireNonNull`: [`This method is designed [for] parameter validation in methods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull)

Comment: @PeterRader sorry if my comment sounded like IAE must be used over NPE, there's really no right or wrong answer for this holy war within Java. :) Take whichever makes your method signature more consistent, and it seems like you have already justified your usage. All is good...